# Does an existing gruntfile need to be edited? What is the common workflow?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

For an existing app, is there a proper protocol for specifying bower packages such that they're handled correctly when running "grunt build"?  Does an existing gruntfile need to be edited?  What is the common workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very abroad...  If you are using a 3rd party package that is not yours, you don't need to edit the `gruntfile.js`. However the `gruntfile.js` for your app will be created/edited to fit your app needs.

Comment: I can confirm this behaves differently between my two projects.  One of them works fine after moving the api script references in index.html.  The other project still seems to break after running build.

Comment: the project that works fine is the one I started from scratch.  The other has two bower_components folders.  One in root and one in /app.  Is this common?